# Codigos IR obtenidos de Arduino en android studio

Tags: android, arduino

Estoy utilizando una placa arduino para capturar los códigos de los controles remotos de mi casa para posteriormente hacer un control remoto universal con android studio. No tengo experiencia en IR. En arduino logro obtener los codigos de esta forma

```
Protocol:3 
Address:FD 
Command:6897
```

o de esta.

```
0: 9052
1: 4456
2: 576
3: 552
4: 576
5: 540
...................
```

es decir hex o RAW. Pero aparentemente android stuidio utiliza pronto hex. Hay alguna función de android studio que acepte raw? de no ser así como puedo convertir de raw a pronto hex? Gracias de antemano. Saludos